# If server returns 404, proxy_pass to alternative server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, web, webserver

I couldn't find anything specifically related to this problem on google or on here, so apologize if I'm maybe just not using the right terms.

I'm moving terabytes of data to a new server due to bandwidth issues (need a higher-bandwidth port), and to make this as seamless as possible I want to move the site to it's new server before the transfer is finished. I then want new uploads to be fetched from the new server, and then if that server returns a 404, it should be passed along to the old server.

What's the best way to do this with nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Try in your config file for nginx add these rows

```
 location / {
   error_page 404 =301 http://yoursecondsite.com/;
 }
```

after adding call `nginx -t` for checking syntax and reload `systemctl reload nginx`

Comment: It can't be a redirect, it has to proxy to another IP address (the old one) in order to keep compatability with third party services intact while the move is going down

Comment: @Doodles You need reverse proxy?